# LinqToSql Dynamic Insert

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I currently have a Linq to Sql implementation that takes forever long to do the inserts, so I am trying to speed it up using a compact insert statement, but still using linq to sql's execute command.

I have a `string[]` that I am trying to pass into ExecuteCommand's `object[] parameters` parameter like so.

```
string sqlStart = "INSERT INTO BusinessContacts (Guid,BusinessId,Name,Email,Address,City,State,PostalCode,Phone,URL) VALUES ";
string sqlParams = "(NewId(),1,{{{0}}},{{{1}}},{{{2}}},{{{3}}},{{{4}}},{{{5}}},{{{6}}},{{{7}}}),";
string[] values = new string[8000];
int curParam = -1;
sbSqlValues.Append(sqlStart);
foreach (var email in emails) {
    sbSqlValues.AppendFormat(sqlParams, ++curParam, ++curParam, ++curParam, ++curParam, ++curParam, ++curParam, ++curParam, ++curParam);
    curParam -= 8;
    values[++curParam] = email.Name;
    values[++curParam] = (email.Email);
    values[++curParam] = (email.Address);
    values[++curParam] = (email.City);
    values[++curParam] = (email.State);
    values[++curParam] = (email.PostalCode);
    values[++curParam] = (email.Phone);
    values[++curParam] = (email.URL);
}
sbSqlValues.Remove(sbSqlValues.Length - 1, 1);
inserted += ExecuteCommand(sbSqlValues.ToString(), values);
```

But even though I am passing in an array of strings, I keep getting the exception: `A query parameter cannot be of type 'System.Object'.`

Answer (score 0):

Try: `(object[])values` as the 2nd parameter. The C# compiler converts the `string[]` to a one-element `params`.

Comment: Updated to `ExecuteCommand(sbSqlValues.ToString(), (object[])values);`, still throws the same exception.

Comment: Ok, then please show the SQL you execute as well as what ExecuteCommand is. Provide all information that we need.

Comment: It is a method inside a LINQ to SQL DataContext.

Comment: Make values exactly the right length. My guess is that L2S chokes on the null values in the array. Use the debugger to make sure that you do not send any null values. Please also post the stack trace. If this does not help, create a small, executable repro.

Comment: The `values` length is exactly the right length (1000 inserts @ 8 params each). Also, I'm running this in LINQpad, so I don't have access to a stack trace.

Comment: Ok create a repro then. You have to help a little.